# RegEx Numerical Range 0-35

Tags: regex

I have wrote a regex which validates any number between 0-35 (inclusive). Just wondering if this is correct?

```
([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-5])
```

Further does anyone know a numerical range regex generator? Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine just use anchors or word boundary on both sides.

Comment: Could be simplified to `([1-2]?[0-9]|3[0-5])`

Comment: @Thomas: Do not forget anchors. Wood: See [Generate a Regular Expression to Match an Arbitrary Numeric Range (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/534137-generate-a-regular-expression-to-match-an-arbitrar/). Just paste into [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) and enjoy.

Comment: See more common examples here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html